# Faster algorithm for a specific inversion

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, combinatorics, permutations

There is a permutation (more precisely a derangement) $\sigma$ of the set $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ with cardinality $n$.

I want to compute the following counts (a kind of inversion):

$$K(\sigma )_{i}=\#\{j>i:\sigma _{j}>i\}$$

for each $0 \le i \lt n$.

Obviously a $O(n^2)$ straight-forward algorithm computes these counts. But can it be done faster (eg in $O(n \log n)$)?

I can't seem to wrap my head around such an algorithm, based on [other divide-and-conquer algorihms for usual inversions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/), at least so far.

**Background:** The counts above are used in a custom algorithm to rank and unrank derangements in lexicographic order and their computation is the main bottleneck of the algorithm.

Comment: Visualising the problem helps here. You have got a permutation matrix, represented by recording for each row the column where it has a nonzero entry. In $O(n)$ time, you can get the "transposed" information (corresponding to $\sigma^{-1}$) as well, if you should need it, The problem is to count, for each $i$, the sum of entries in the bottom-right square $(n-i)\times(n-i)$ matrix; by looking at the differences for adjacent $i$, this can be done in a single pass.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each element $j$ contributes $1$ to the cardinality of all sets $\{j > i \mid \sigma_j > i\}$ for which $i < \min\{\sigma_j, j\}$, and $0$ to the other sets.

You can compute all $n$ values $K(\sigma)_i$ in $O(n)$ time as follows.
Maintain an array $A[0, \dots, n-1]$ where each entry $A[i]$ is initialized to $0$.
Then, for each $j$, increment $A[\min\{\sigma_j, j\}]$ by $1$.

Compute the sums of the elements in all suffixes of $A$, i.e., construct a new array $K[1, \dots, n-1]$ such $K[i] = \sum_{i' > i} A[i']$.
This can be done in $O(n)$ time by setting $K[n-1]=0$ and, for all $i=n-2, \dots, 0$ (in this order), $K[i] = K[i+1] + A[i+1]$.

Clearly, the above can also be done in-place without the need of the additional array $K$.

Comment: Excellent! Can a similar strategy be applied to count $K'(\sigma )_{i}=\#\{j<i:\sigma _{j}>i\}$??

Comment: $$|\{ j < i : \sigma_j > i \}| + |\{ j > i : \sigma_j > i \}| + |\{ i : \sigma_i > i \}| = |\{ j \mid \sigma_j > i \}.|$$ Substituting:
$$
K'(\sigma)_i + K(\sigma)_i + 1_{\sigma_i > i} = n-i-1.
$$
Therefore:
$$
K'(\sigma)_i = n-i-1 -  K(\sigma)_i - 1_{\sigma_i > i}
$$

Comment: hmm, $K'(\sigma)$ is needed in unranking, and we dont have $K(\sigma)$ as we dont have yet the permutation, it is built step-by-step

Comment: Uhm... $K'(\sigma)_i$ is defined as a function of sigma. How would you compute $K'(\sigma)_i$ in the first place (even in a non-efficient way) if you don't know $\sigma$?

Comment: $K'(\sigma)$ is based strictly on previous entries

Comment: I see, so only $\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_i$ are known?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Only previously computed entries during unranking are known

Comment: Can a similar linear recursive scheme, be applied in this case? Indeed the two complementary counts are related to the formula you gave earlier

Comment: I don't know if a similar scheme can be applied since you want your answers to be known **online**. However I'm fairly confident that a slightly slower approach works. Perhaps you can post a new question so we don't clutter the comments?

Comment: I dont mind posting a new question, but I am fraid to be marked as duplicate..

Comment: Here is [question part 2](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/142186/faster-algorithm-for-specific-inversion-count-part-2)

Comment: In fact in both ranking and unranking we need $K(\sigma)$, the difference is that when ranking $\sigma$ is given so $K(\sigma)$ can be computed in a straight forward manner, while in unranking the entries of $\sigma$ are built step-by-step so we estimate $K(\sigma)$ using $K'(\sigma)$ which is based strictly on already computed entries and the complement relation $K(\sigma)_i = n-i-1 -  K'(\sigma)_i - 1_{\sigma_i > i}$

Comment: I try to derive this, according to my analysis:
$$\#\{j>i:\sigma _{j}>i\}=\#\{j \ge i+1:\sigma _{j}=i+1\}+\#\{j>i+1:\sigma _{j}>i+1\}$$
Substituting:
$$K(\sigma)_i = A'_{i+1} + K(\sigma)_{i+1}$$
With $A'_i = \#\{j \ge i:\sigma _{j}=i\}$, but I cannot relate analyticaly my $A'_i$ to your $A_i = \#\{\min(\sigma_j, j) > i\}$. What am i missing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127416/discussion-between-steven-and-nikos-m).