# Faster algorithm for specific inversion count (part 2)

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, combinatorics, permutations

Following the issue from [Faster algorithm for a specific inversion](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/142180/faster-algorithm-for-a-specific-inversion):

We have a permutation (a derangement actually) $\sigma$ of the set $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ with cardinality $n$.

I want to compute certain counts (a kind of inversion):

$$K'(\sigma )_{i}=\#\{j<i:\sigma _{j}>i\}$$

for each $0 \le i \lt n$.

With the restriction that the computation should depend **strictly on previously computed entries** (as this is for unranking, the future entries of the permutation are not yet known).

For computing the complementary counts during ranking (the linked question), there is a linear algorithm rather than the straight-forward $O(n^2)$ algorithm.

Can a faster algorithm (than the straight-forward $O(n^2)$ computation) be applied also in this case (maybe linear or $O(n \log n)$)?

**Background:** The counts above are used in a custom algorithm to rank and unrank derangements in lexicographic order and their computation is the main bottleneck of the algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each $j$ contributes $1$ to all $K'(\sigma)_i$ with $j < i < \sigma_j$.

Ideally you want a data structure that maintains a collection of $n$ counters $C_0, \dots, C_{n-1}$ under the following operations:

- Offset($j$, $\delta$): Given $j$ and $\delta$, add $\delta$ to each $C_i$ with $i \le j$.
- Evaluate($i$): Return the value of $C_i$

When $\sigma_j$ is revealed, you can add $1$ to all  $C_i$ with $j < i < \sigma_j$ (assuming the interval is non-empty) by performing the following two operations: (i) Offset($\sigma_j-1$, $1$), (ii) Offset($j$, $-1$).
Then, you can recover the value of $K'(\sigma)_i$ by performing a Evaluate($i$) operation.

The rest of the answers describes how to implement a data structure supporting each of the above operations in $O(\log n)$ time, so that the overall time complexity will be $O(n \log n)$.

Suppose for simplicity that $n$ is a power of $2$, so that $k = \log n$.
Instead of keeping a single set of counters $C_0, \dots, C_{n-1}$ (i.e., one for each $i$)  keep multiple counters per element $i$.

The counters associated with $i$ will be $C^{(h)}_i$ for some suitably chosen values of $h$.
In particular, if the binary expansion of $i$ has $\ell_i$ zeros in its least significant bit, then we will keep $\ell_i$ counters $C^{(0)}_i, C^{(1)}_i, \dots, C^{(\ell_i-1)}_i$. (If $\ell_i=0$, we keep no counters). The intuition is that adding $1$ to $C_i^{(h)}$ corresponds to adding $1$ to each of the $2^h$ "original counters" $C_i, C_{i+1}, \dots, C_{i+2^{h}-1}$. In particular we say that $C_i^{(h)}$ *covers* $C_i, C_{i+1}, \dots, C_{i+2^{h}-1}$.

See the figure for a graphical example with $n=16$.

[image: example]

To implement Offset($j$, $\delta$): write $j+1$ as a sum of (at most $\log n$) decreasing distinct powers of $2$ so that $j+1 = 2^{h_1} + 2^{h_2} + 2^{h_3} + \dots + 2^{h_m}$. Do the following:

- Set $x = 0$.
- For each $\ell = 1, \dots, m$:

  - Increment $C^{(h_\ell)}_x$ by $\delta$.
  - Increment $x$ by $2^{h_\ell}$.

For example when $j = 12$, we can write $j+1 = 13$ as $8 + 4 + 1 = 2^3 + 2^2 + 2^0$.
To perform Offset($12$, $1$), we would add $1$ to $C_{0}^{(3)}$, $C_{8}^{(2)}$, $C_{12}^{(0)}$. These are exactly the counters corresponding to the intervals highlighted in red.

To recover the value of the "original counter" $C_i$, it suffices to sum the values of all counters $C_{i'}^{(h)}$ that cover $C_i$.

Comment: $O(n \log n)$ seems way better than $O(n^2)$, however I will implement the idea and get back to you. Thank you!

Comment: I cant seem to make it work correctly. I think the problem is in Offset(). Why is $j+1$ needed instead of $j$? The rest are straight-forward.

Comment: Note that $0 \le j \le n-1$, $0 \le \sigma_j \le n-1$, so $\sigma_j-1$ can become invalid value

Comment: I wrote down a [quick implementation](https://pastebin.com/HV9ihYGT) in C++, which appears to be working fine. Also, notice that I wrote that you need to perform the two offset operations only if the interval $j < i < \sigma_j$ is non-empty.

Comment: The quantity $j+1$ represents the number of "original counters" we have to logically change  when offset($j$, $\delta$) is called. $j+1$ (instead of $j$) is correct here since this is affecting the $j+1$ counters $C_0, C_1, \dots, C_{j}$.

Comment: Unfortunately it still does not work, I used your code (adapted to JavaScript) but still does not produce correct results!

Comment: Debugging is off-topic, but if you can provide a list of Offset$(j, \delta)$ operations, followed by an Evaluate$(i)$ operation that returns the incorrect result I'll check my implementation.

Comment: Where can I post those?

Comment: Any pastebin website, for example [here](https://pastebin.com/).

Comment: pasted [here](https://pastebin.com/QupV5PY0) the implementation code along with an example unranking where wrong results are produced (all the steps of eval and offset are given). Note that it fails only in certain cases, other times it works fine

Comment: first offset is $\sigma_j-1$ and second offset is $j$

Comment: I'm sorry I'm having troubles interpreting the comments at the beginning of the file. (I didn't look at the code as I don't want to debug your code). Can you tell me how to interpret the "eval" lines? Also can you tell me the first operation that returns an incorrect result so I can test it on my implementation?

Comment: k is the correct value and eval is the returned value from eval \

Comment: they are produced in the order that they happen, so first eval then an element is revealed followed by the offset operations, then again next loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127663/discussion-between-steven-and-nikos-m).

Comment: Ok managed to make it work. It was a combination of a typo from my part plus carefull handling of bitwise operations in JS since they are treated always as 32bit signed integers (so take care of sign). Thank you!